# Are hands rendered tumah if water flowed down after second or third pour?

Tags: tamei-tahor-ritual-purity, netilat-yadayim-washing

When performing morning netilat yadayim, are the hands rendered tumah if during the second or third pour the water is poured above the wrists?

Comment: Why would they? The reason for 3 pours in the morning is because the ruach ra only goes away after 3. By netilas yadayim for bread the second one is to wash away the first one that is tammeh but not in the morning

Answer (score 0):

According to the Chayei Adam, the tumah of the morning only applies to the fingers (C.A. 2:1) so water originating above that point won't bring tumah down to the fingers.